# ssh breaks while look despite of ssh -n

Tags: bash, shell

ssh breaks while look despite of ssh -n

I need to ssh into several server and run some command there. Unfortunately ssh in while loop breaks the loop

There is a hosts.txt:

```
10.168.2.27
10.168.3.95
```

And this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
while read f1
do
     echo "Logging into $f1"   
     ssh root@$f1 'hostname; uptime' < /dev/null

done <"$filename"
```

I have tried the ssh -n as well, but the result always the same the loop is broken after the 1st line of the hosts.txt

What is wrong with my script ?

Comment: Just to confirm, do the remote commands execute successfully, and does the loop iterate over the entire file if `ssh` is commented out? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, does hosts.txt really only have two lines? One possibility is that it isn't breaking after the first line so much as it is exiting on the *last* line (which would happen if host.txt didn't end with a newline character).

Comment: Ahhhh so stupid mistake..
There was no newline at the end of the 2nd line :) Thx to pointing me to that.

Answer (score 1):

`read` has a non-zero exit status if it doesn't find a newline, so although it will read in whatever remains from the file, the body of the loop won't be entered. There are two solutions:

1. Make sure you are reading from a POSIX-compliant text file, which means *every* line is terminated by `\n`.
2. Change your condition to

   ```
   while read f1 || [ -n "$f1" ]; do
   ```

   which will have a non-zero exit status as long as `read` is able to read *something*.

The first option is preferable.